# переполнение pipe

Tags: c++, pipes

Пишу эмюляцию конвейера shell, есть уже распаршенный список команд (см. структуру command). Программа корректно отрабатывает, когда ее вывод небольшой, на пример ls | more. Однако, когда вывод программы очень большой, на пример ls -lR /* | more, то программа крашается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать функцию run_pipe() чтобы процессы могли обмениваться и большими объемами информации:
код:

```
struct command
{
    vector<char*> argv;
    command* follow_pipe;  //следующая, если конвейер


    command() {
        follow_pipe = 0;
    }
};

void pipe_run (command* ptr) {
    pid_t pid, wpid;
    int pfd[2], input, status;
    bool first = true;
    while (ptr != nullptr ) {
        pipe(pfd);
        if (!(pid = fork())) {
            if (!first) {
                dup2(input, 0);
                close(input);
            }
            if ( ptr->follow_pipe != nullptr )
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            execvp( ptr->argv[0], &ptr->argv[0]);
            cerr<<"exec_vp"<<'\n';
        }
        if (!first)
            close(input);
        close(pfd[1]);
        input = pfd[0];
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        first = false;
        ptr = ptr->follow_pipe;
    }
}
```

update: добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример (структура command была немного изменена, но это никак не влияет на проблему при тех же тестах):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct command
{
    char** argv;

    command* follow_pipe;  //следующая, если конвейер


    command() {
        argv = 0; 
        follow_pipe = 0;
    }

};


void pipe_run (command* ptr) {
    pid_t pid, wpid;
    int pfd[2], input, status;
    bool first = true;
    while (ptr != nullptr ) {
        pipe(pfd);
        if (!(pid = fork())) {
            if (!first) {
                dup2(input, 0);
                close(input);
            }
            if ( ptr->follow_pipe != nullptr )
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            execvp( ptr->argv[0], &ptr->argv[0]);
        }
        if (!first)
            close(input);
        close(pfd[1]);
        input = pfd[0];
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
        first = false;
        ptr = ptr->follow_pipe;
    }
}


int main () {
    command* temp1 = new command;
    command* temp2 =  new command;

    vector<string> A(3), B(1);
    A[0] = "ls";
    A[1] = "-lR";
    A[2] = "/";  // при запуске в маленькой дирректории и без добавления этого аргумента программа работает корректно
    B[0] = "more";

    temp1->argv = new char* [A.size() +1 ];
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < A.size() ; ++i ) {
        temp1->argv[i] = new char[A[i].size()];
        strcpy( temp1->argv[i], A[i].c_str() );
    }
    temp1->argv[A.size()] = nullptr;

    temp2->argv = new char* [B.size() +1 ];
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < B.size() ; ++i ) {
        temp2->argv[i] = new char[B[i].size()];
        strcpy( temp2->argv[i], B[i].c_str() );
    }
    temp2->argv[B.size()] = nullptr;

    temp1->follow_pipe = temp2;
    pipe_run(temp1);
}
```

Comment: в приведённом коде вроде ничего особо криминального не видно... разве что утечка дескрипторов в основном процессе и нет обработки ошибки `fork()`/`exec()`... чтобы сказать, что не так, нужен [mcve]...

Comment: @Fat-Zer , добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример, обработки ошибок пока не добавлял, хотел сделать это на самом последнем этапе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в вопросе в том, что сначала запускается один элемент конвейера и сразу ожидается его окончание. Само собой если этот процесс не завершается, пытаясь писать в трубу, из которой ни кто не читает то всё зависает. Нужно сначала запустить **все** элементы конвейера, а уже потом ждать их завершения. т.е. цикл с `waitpid()`'ами должны идти после цикла запуска. *PID*'ы всех потомков соответственно нужно предварительно сохранить. в итоге это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
struct command
{
    // ...
    int pid;
};

void pipe_run (command* ptr) {
    pid_t wpid;
    int pfd[2], input, status;
    bool first = true;
    for (command *cmd=ptr; cmd; cmd = cmd->follow_pipe) {
        pipe(pfd);
        if (!(cmd->pid = fork())) {
            if (!first) {
                dup2(input, 0);
                close(input);
            }
            if ( cmd->follow_pipe != nullptr )
                dup2(pfd[1], 1);
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            execvp( cmd->argv[0], &cmd->argv[0]);
        }
        if (!first)
            close(input);
        close(pfd[1]);
        input = pfd[0];
        first = false;
    }
    for (command *cmd=ptr; cmd; cmd = cmd->follow_pipe) {
        do {
            wpid = waitpid(cmd->pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, все работает, ошибку понял.